# Where is the interface documentation for IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

In every IdentityServer4 Quick Start sample there are in-memory providers given for the resources, clients, and users. Are there any samples of the proper interface overrides needed for production?

For instance IProfileService is the class to be overridden for user management, however there are no examples that use this class and there is no specification in the reference section as to what the members of this class are. When implementing it you get the methods you need to override, but all the return types are Task and there is no helpful commentary on the specifics.

Comment: There's no `IProfileManager` in IdentityServer which interface do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and ended up looking at the default implementations (the way the IdentityServer4 implements these interfaces) [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/dev/src/IdentityServer4/Services).

There's no `IProfileManager` so if you mean `IProfileService` here's how we're using it (to add claims to the access_token):

```
public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>();

    context.IssuedClaims = claims;
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

You can now add your claims to that claims list and they will be added to the access_token which will be returned to the client.